# Dynamically assign outbound network interface

Tags: routing, network-interface

I'm establishing a network connection with wvdial (PPP) and I want to assign this as the outgoing network interface AFTER it is established.

The connection is being established by a bash script and after it is established I would require it to change the outbound interface.

The current network interface file looks like this:

```
# This file describes the network interfaces available on your system
# and how to activate them. For more information, see interfaces(5).

# The loopback network interface
auto lo eth0
iface lo inet loopback
iface eth0 inet static
        address 192.168.1.123
        netmask 255.255.255.0
        gateway 192.168.1.1

#auto lo usb0
iface usb0 inet static
    address 192.168.7.2
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    network 192.168.7.0
    gateway 192.168.7.1
```

As you can see the PPP connection is not displayed anywhere.

**Questions:**

- I want to be able to access the machine via it's eth interface over
  SSH
- I want that all other traffic to go over PPP

Answer (score 0):

If you are consuming PPPoE service, use `pppoeconfig`. pppd has `defaultroute` and `replacedefaultroute` options. You can append `route add default <dev>`, where 'dev' is the brought up interface name like ppp0, to your script.

Comment: Hello @nizammohamed, what happens after I add the route default <dev> command? Does all the traffic than go over that interface? Am I still be able to login to the machine via ssh?

Comment: `netstat -rn` lists routes. if 'Destination' coloumn has '0.0.0.0' then you already have default route. If no the said command adds one. Default route is selected by kernel when making routing decision for a destination if no other route matches. eth0 has a private 'ip'. If you are connected to the interface somehow, you can or should you want to connect thru ppp0, ensure sshd is listening on ppp0 or 0.0.0.0 wildcard.

Comment: If there is no PPP device at the beginning (the device is connected and the connection is established AFTER that) would that still work?